# Can a managed package access and render a Visualforce page from the default namespace or a different namespace?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, namespace, renderas

A managed package implementing the PageReference's method `getContentAsPDF` implements a certain logic that allows the name of the page being called to be dynamic.

Is it possible that this Apex code in a managed package accesses a page in the org's default namespace or a Visualforce page in a different namespace?

I'm asking because with my attempted implementation I keep getting an error in a subscriber org (which is my dev org, actually) when calling the code from a flow:

> Error Occurred: null

I'm fairly sure Salesforce hides the actual error and replaces with "null" because its a managed package. Still, this doesn't happen when the code is not managed.

Comment: I would say yes, since we invoke rendering of unpackaged Visualforce pages as PDFs from our managed package.

Answer (score 0):

Our managed package code does something similar to what you suggest, along the lines of the following (not showing error handling):

```
PageReference pdf = new PageReference(pageName);

pdf.getParameters().put('id', someId);

Blob generatedPDF = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
```

The `pageName` is of the form Base URL + '/apex/pageName'. That page might be something like:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Invoice__c" extensions="Invoice24HrExtension" showHeader="false"
                       sidebar="false">
  ...
</apex:page>
```

Note that the controller extension is just a public class; it did not need to be global to allow the page to be rendered from managed package code.